Thunderbird shows subfolders twice
Since recently, TB has started showing subfolders twice:

Normally under the main folder
As grey and italic folders under Inbox in the format Mainfolder_subfolder (see the screenshot)


Those grey folders do not have a subscribe/unsubscribe checkbox so I cannot unsubscribe from them. I wonder if anyone has this problem.
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Thunderbird  115.15.0 (64-bit)

please [edit] your question to indicate which version of Ubuntu and which version of TB you are using. I see no issue with your graphic but have you investigated settings with View -> Folders and View -> Layout I see no problems with the deb version on 22.04.5 with TB version 115.15.0

Thanks a lot. I have added versions. View>Folders and View>Layout unfortunately do not provide any relevant options.

is this the Snap version or the .deb version of TB and was it a clean install or as a result of an upgrade from an earlier Ubuntu version? Curious that my version of TB is the same but with v22.04.5

It's from a repository and installed with Synaptic. Also, I have just realised. I've got a few IMAP email accounts in Thunderbird and those grey folders only appear on one account.
